# MapStruct mapping nested beans as is

Tags: java, mapstruct

My question is how to map object contains nested object to DTO as is, not a value from the nested object, for example if there is 2 classes like this :

```
    public class TestClass {
        @Id
        private String id;

        @Field("field1")
        private String field1;

        @Field("field2")
        private Long field2;

        @Field("nestedClass")
        private NestedClass;

        //getter & setter 
    }

    public class NestedClass {
    //fields and getter and setter for it
    }

    DTO classes looks like :

    public class TestClassDTO {
        private String id;
        private String field1;
        private Long field2;
        private NestedClassDTO ;

        //getter & setter 
    }

    public class NestedClassDTO {
        //fields and getter and setter for it
    }


    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
    public interface TestClassMapper {

        TestClassDTO TestClassToTestClassDTO(TestClass TestClass);

        TestClass TestClassDTOToTestClass(TestClassDTO TestClassDTO);

        NestedClass NestedClassDTOToNestedClass(NestedClassDTO NestedClassDTO);

        NestedClassDTO NestedClassToNestedClassDTO(NestedClass NestedClass);

        }
```

after invoking TestClassDTOToTestClass() and sending TestClassDTO contains NestedClassDTO .. it is return TestClass with null NestedClass .. is it possible to map it without write my own mapper ?

SH

Answer (score 2):

I found it :)

the mapper class should use the nestedclass like this :

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {NestedClassMapper.class})
    public interface TestClassMapper {

        TestClassDTO TestClassToTestClassDTO(TestClass TestClass);

        TestClass TestClassDTOToTestClass(TestClassDTO TestClassDTO);

        NestedClass NestedClassDTOToNestedClass(NestedClassDTO NestedClassDTO);

        NestedClassDTO NestedClassToNestedClassDTO(NestedClass NestedClass);

    }
```

Comment: If your `TestClassMapper` really looks like this, then you should not need `NestedClassMapper`. The reason for this is that the mapping between `NestedClass` and `NestedClassDTO` and the opposite is already defined in the `TestClassMapper`.

Comment: I'm not sure why.. but it didn't work without add NestedClassMapper.class in uses @Mapper

Comment: If that was the case it might be a bug. Can you perhaps share the `NestedClassMapper` as well, so I can have a better look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Names of the field in the TestClass and TestClassDTO must be the same, then you won't need all this `(componentModel = "spring", uses = {NestedClassMapper.class})`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you want to have a mapping method that will not map (ignore) the `nestedClass`field from the `TestClassDTO`. You can use [`@Mapping#ignore`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#ignore--).

Your mapper will look something like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface TestClassMapper {

    TestClassDTO TestClassToTestClassDTO(TestClass TestClass);

    @Mapping(target = "nestedClass", ignore = true)
    TestClass TestClassDTOToTestClass(TestClassDTO TestClassDTO);

    NestedClass NestedClassDTOToNestedClass(NestedClassDTO NestedClassDTO);

    NestedClassDTO NestedClassToNestedClassDTO(NestedClass NestedClass);

    }
```

If for some reason you want explicitly set the value to `null` then have a look a the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347620/set-null-to-target-using-mastruct/43353867)

Comment: no..actually I want to map it.. I don't know why it is not mapped and return the value as nul.. may be I should use     @Mapping(target = "nestedClass", ignore = false)

Comment: Can you tell me what are the names of the fields for the nested classes in the TestClass?

Comment: it is normal fields lets say it is String field1, String field2

Comment: or better to call it String nestedField

Comment: I meant the name of the field in the `TestClass` and `TestClassDTO`